# redirect to another resources folder on a condition in android

Tags: android

android application gets all its resources from res folder which is default.I have created a new res-new folder and have the elements with same tag name as res folder but a different value. Is there a way to set the application to pick resources from res-new folder pragmatically?

I have gone though the developers site, all i could see is to change the resource folder depending on locale,MCC and MNC which is taken care but android OS.
I'm looking for a way to change complete look and feel of my app by using resources from a new resource folder with a condition.

Comment: Writing some new custom qualifiers for Android? It depends entirely on your use case. On what condition do you want your new resources to be triggered? Please be specific. Many people have asked to write their own custom qualifiers for Android, but more often than not, it's because they didn't understand how the system of qualifiers worked in the first place, so telling them how to rewrite it themselves would have done more harm than good (so in those cases, it's just easier to tell them that it's just not possible).

Answer (score 0):

> I'm looking for a way to change complete look and feel of my app by using resources from a new resource folder with a condition.

It's not possible to have multiple resource folders in the way you are trying to do it. You can create different styles for views and themes however.

See [Styles and Themes](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Comment: If i add different styles and themes, can i make the application to force use the resources from these new xml files.